# Change input date format when using Knockout.js to mm/yyyy

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to change the date input format for two dates in our application, but not for the rest of the app.  These two inputs need to collect the month and year mm/yyyy.  Currently they are collecting it in this format mm/dd/yyyy.  We are using Knockout.js

```
    <li>
        <label class="required_label">Date of Event</label>
        <input style="width: 140px;" type="text" data-bind="date: eventDate" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="required_label">Date of Lawsuit</label>
        <input style="width: 140px;" type="text" data-bind="date: lawsuitDate" />
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a new binding handler called date2 to the DateHandler file

```
<li>
    <label class="required_label">Date of Event</label>
    <input style="width: 140px;" type="text" data-bind="date2: eventDate" />
</li>
<li>
    <label class="required_label">Date of Lawsuit</label>
    <input style="width: 140px;" type="text" data-bind="date2: lawsuitDate" />
</li>

/// <reference path="../../typings/moment/moment.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../typings/masked.input/masked.input.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../typings/knockout.validation/knockout.validation.d.ts" />

interface KnockoutBindingHandlers {
    date: KnockoutBindingHandler;
    date2: KnockoutBindingHandler;
}

// mm/dd/yyyy format
ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
    init: (element, valueAccessor) => {
        $(element).mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy" });

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", () => {
            var value = valueAccessor();

            if (moment(element.value).isValid()) {
                value(element.value);
            } else {
                value(null);
            }
        });

        ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable("date");
    },
    update: (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) => {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped: any = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
        var pattern = allBindings.format || "MM/DD/YYYY";
        var output = null;

        if (valueUnwrapped !== null && valueUnwrapped !== undefined && valueUnwrapped.length > 0) {
            output = moment(valueUnwrapped).format(pattern);
        }

        if ($(element).is("input") === true) {
            $(element).val(output);
        } else {
            $(element).text(output);
        }
    }
};


//  mm/yyyy format
ko.bindingHandlers.date2 = {
    init: (element, valueAccessor) => {
        //$(element).mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy" });
        $(element).mask("99/9999", { placeholder: "mm/yyyy" });

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", () => {
            var value = valueAccessor();

            if (moment(element.value).isValid()) {
                value(element.value);
            } else {
                value(null);
            }
        });

        ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable("date");
    },
    update: (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) => {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped: any = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
        //var pattern = allBindings.format || "MM/DD/YYYY";
        var pattern = allBindings.format || "MM/YYYY";
        var output = null;

        if (valueUnwrapped !== null && valueUnwrapped !== undefined && valueUnwrapped.length > 0) {
            output = moment(valueUnwrapped).format(pattern);
        }

        if ($(element).is("input") === true) {
            $(element).val(output);
        } else {
            $(element).text(output);
        }
    }
};

ko.validation.rules["simpleDate"] = {
    validator: (val: any, validate: any) => {
        if (val == null) return true;

        return moment(val).isValid();
    },
    message: "Invalid date"
};
```